# Use of Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect

I am not sure whether I have used Present Perfect correctly in the following sentence: 
"Influenced by my academic background and experience, my research interests are diverse and interdisciplinary. *They have been shaped by the academic programs that I have completed, which provided me with good foundations to explore different topics in the field of English Linguistics, Literature and Culture*. 
Can you help me out?

Comment: In the subordinate clause you switch from perfect to past, when you say *which provided me with...*. Had I written the first part of the sentence in the perfect, I think I would have tended to continue *which have provided me...*. It doesn't stand out as a great error, but I think it flows rather better and has a stronger grammatical claim.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to change ***provided*** to ***provides***.

---

This is a suggested rewrite:

*The academic programs that I completed have shaped my diverse and interdisciplinary research interests. This **provides** me with a good foundation to explore different topics in the field of English Linguistics, Literature and Culture.*